# How to display the published date instead of last modified in this particular Wordpress code snippet

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the way post dates are displayed in my Wordpress child theme. As of now the time shown is the last modified, and I want it to be the date I manually set in each post (i.e. original publication date).

I have found a file in the parent theme that I think might contain the code culprit. I admit I don't quite understand what this code does though, and I've been trying by trial and error to make it work in a different way, even to the point of deleting it entirely, but to no avail. Whatever I do, the output on my page remains the same. There haven't even been any error messages, either. I have a suspicion that the file in question, which I copied to the child theme's folder, isn't somehow properly queued and thus no changes are reflected. The file is called 'template-tags.php' and it resides in a folder called 'inc'. I have created an analoguous folder in my child theme's directory and copied the file there for editing.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'writings_posted_on' ) ) :
    /**
     * Prints HTML with meta information for the current post-date/time and author.
     */
    function writings_posted_on() {
        $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
        if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
            $time_string = '<time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time><time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
        }

        $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
            esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_date() ),
            esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
            esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
        );

        $posted_on = sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: post date. */
            esc_html_x( 'Posted on %s', 'post date', 'writings' ),
            '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
        );

        $byline = sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: post author. */
            esc_html_x( 'by %s', 'post author', 'writings' ),
            '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a></span>'
        );

        echo '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span><span class="byline"> ' . $byline . '</span>'; // WPCS: XSS OK.

    }
```

I expect the output on the page to be the original publication date, and not last modified date as it is now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the main function to the child theme and customize as per your requirement.  I have modified the function to ignore updated date in the post meta. You can try following. Copy following code in the `functions.php` of your child theme and paste it.

```
function writings_posted_on() {
    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';

    $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() )
    );

    $posted_on = sprintf(
        /* translators: %s: post date. */
        esc_html_x( 'Posted on %s', 'post date', 'writings' ),
        '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
    );

    $byline = sprintf(
        /* translators: %s: post author. */
        esc_html_x( 'by %s', 'post author', 'writings' ),
        '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="' . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . '">' . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . '</a></span>'
    );

    echo '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span><span class="byline"> ' . $byline . '</span>'; // WPCS: XSS OK.

}
```